# Android same line text views

Tags: android, xml

In my android application I want to implement 2 text fields in the same line. if the text is so long okay to go to next line. So I used horizontal leaner layout and added the 2 text fields.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
<TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView></LinearLayout>
```

[Eg: TextView1, TextView2]

The problem is when the text of TextView1 is bit long it still try to print all in one line and mess up.

The result I want is,

if

TextView1 = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & TextView2 = bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, bbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbb
```

does anyone one have any idea of how to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="This is the textview1 in the linearlayout"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#0a30aa"
    />
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="this is textview2 in the linearlayout"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#990099"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

property to your textviews that will be do the job.

Comment: I want to print textView1 content in one line and if for textview 2 not enough go to next line. (for example if textView1 is aaaaaaaaaaaaa and textview2 is bbbbbbbbbbb, then type aaaaaaaaaa in one line then if the space not enough to type bbbbbbbbb type as much as possible in same line and half of bbbbbbb go to next line).  When I add android:layout_weight="1", type half of textview1 in one line other half next line and same thing for TextView2